# Customizing XmlSerialize output

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm creating an xml file with the xmlserialize class, the output that I get is nearly what I need.
This is what I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <pdf file-name="C:\Users\d.sassoli\Desktop\media\mergiato.pdf" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <document>
  <document start-page="1">
   <SheetChange>
     <SheetChange sheet-type="A4" page-number="1"/>
     <SheetChange sheet-type="A3" page-number="2"/>
    </SheetChange>
 </document>
</pdf>
```

This is what I want

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <pdf file-name="C:\Users\d.sassoli\Desktop\media\mergiato.pdf" >
  <document start-page="1">
     <SheetChange sheet-type="A4" page-number="1"/>
     <SheetChange sheet-type="A3" page-number="2"/>
</pdf>
```

And these are my classes where I define the structure of my xml

```
   [XmlRootAttribute("pdf", IsNullable = false)]
public class Pdf
{
    private Pdf() { }
    public static Pdf Builder()
    {
        Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
        return pdf;
    }
    [XmlAttribute("file-name")]
    public List<string> FileName { get; set; }
    public List<document> document;

}
public class document 
{

    private document() { }
    public static document Builder()
    {
        document doc = new document();
        return doc;
    }
    [XmlAttribute("last-page")] public string LastPage;
    [XmlAttribute("start-page")] public string StartPage;
    public List<SheetChange> SheetChange;

}
public class SheetChange
{
    private SheetChange() { }
    public static SheetChange Builder()
    {
        SheetChange sheetChange = new SheetChange();
        return sheetChange;
    }
    [XmlAttribute("page-number")]
    public string PageNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("sheet-type")]
    public string SheetType { get; set; }
}
```

I tried fiddling around with the xmlattribute but didn't achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IXMLSerializable` interface for your class. Then override ReadXML and WriteXML methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

You can find some examples of using these methods.